# How to compute loss manually in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am using a loss function:

```py
meanAbsoluteError = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()
```

And a model:

```py
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001), loss=meanAbsoluteError)
```

Now I train it and get the history:

```py
history = model.fit(train_features, train_labels, epochs=100, validation_data=(test_features, test_labels))
```

I can check how low the loss has become at the end:

```py
print(history.history["val_loss"][-1])
```

Now I try to compute the loss for the test data manually, using the same data as passed in `validation_data` when training:

```py
print(meanAbsoluteError(model(test_features), test_labels).numpy())
```

But this gives me a completely different number! In my opinion this should equal the loss I got from the previous expression. But that's not the case.

Why the two numbers are not equal, and which one is the correct loss?

I checked how to call the loss function here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Loss#call

I edited this to use `history.history["val_loss"]` instead of `history.history["loss"]` as suggested, but it doesn't fix it.

Comment: If you want to see the number for test data lost, it should be in `history.history["val_loss"]`

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be correct, but the numbers are still off. I edited the question to account for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be caused by the batch size.
The loss in `history['val_loss']` is calculated on the batch. If your `test_features` has a different size than your training batch, it will give you a larger loss.

You should try:

```
print(meanAbsoluteError(model(test_features[:batch_size]), test_labels[:batch_size]).numpy())
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems like I should have indeed used `val_loss`. However, the values are still very different! For example, `history.history["loss"][-1]` is about `1.8`, `history.history["val_loss"][-1]` is about `1.9`, but `meanAbsoluteError(model(test_features), test_labels).numpy()` is about `9.1`. I'd expect it to be the exact same number as the `val_loss` one but that's not the case :(